# Length of a list in a loop

Tags: python, list

I was playing around with a small program that should find the average of numbers and the list of below, above average numbers in that list.

```
num = input("Enter a number: ")

total = 0
count = 0
lst = []

below_ave = []
equal_ave = []
above_ave = []

while num != '':
    n = int(num)
    total += n
    count += 1
    lst.append(n)
    num = input("Enter a number: ")

average = total // count

for i in range(0, len(lst)-1): # Here why it should be len(lst) instead of len(lst)-1
                               # I played around with it a bit, if i use len(lst)-1 then 
                               # the last number in the list (lst) will not be displayed
                               # But as you can see i tried to see if i made a mistake by 
                               # printing out each individual element of the list, lst[4] 
                               # does print out the last number, but it does not show up 
                               # in above_ave. 
    if lst[i] < average:
        below_ave.append(lst[i])
    elif lst[i] == average:
        equal_ave.append(lst[i])
    elif lst[i] > average:
        above_ave.append(lst[i])

print(lst[0])
print(lst[1])
print(lst[2])
print(lst[3])
print(lst[4])

print(f"lentgh of the list is {len(lst)}")

print(average)
print(below_ave)
print(equal_ave)
print(above_ave)
```

```
output
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 8
Enter a number: 6
Enter a number: 12
Enter a number: 9
Enter a number: 
5
8
6
12
9
lentgh of the list is 5
8
[5, 6]
[8]
[12]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As commented in the program. I'm confused with the index of the element in a list. 0th element should represent the first element in a list, however, the output of the program does not show that. I have encountered this problem before, i ignored it but i don't think i should.

So when should one use len(list)-1 and len(list) in similar situations like mine? I usually use len(list)-1 and it works but sometimes it doesn't like in this code.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I personally never use `len(lst) - 1` in python since if you take a look:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    print(lst[i])
```

Here `i` iterates through `0, 1, 2, 3` which would return the output being `1, 2, 3, 4`. However, if you do `len(lst) - 1` then you would not get the last element in the list i.e you wouldn't get `i as 3` and the `output as 4`. `range()` simply omits the last integer passed.

For example:

```
for i in range(0, 10): # You can omit the starting 0 since it is default
   print(i) # Output: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Here as you can see you won't get `10` as the output since `range()` tends to omit the last value.

Using `len(lst) - 1` is not recommended however you could use them if you have pre-defined integers that are co-related with your lst.

**Improvement in Code:**
On `Line 11` where you are checking if `num != ''` I would recommend to check if the input is a digit or no. Check it like: `while not num.isdigit()`
The `isdigit()` is a default keyword which helps you check if all the values in a string are integers or no.

On your last line there is no need to use an `elif` condition to check if the value is greater than average. You can simply use `else` since all the above conditions aren't met so the last one meets by default.

You can also try surfing through [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) methods

Comment: For loops do not omit the last value on their own. The range function iterates from start value to (end value - 1), which is why the last value is never passed to the loop when a range is used.

Answer (score 0):

The length of your list is 5, correct.

However you do a `len(list) - 1` your loop will run 1 iteration less, thus not display the last element that was stored at the end of the list which is 9.

You also printed out average twice with:

```
print(average)
print(equal_ave)
```

In other words:
This is your list `[5,8,6,12,9]`
With their positions respectively

```
lst[0] = 5
lst[1] = 8
lst[2] = 6
lst[3] = 12
lst[4] = 9
```

If your loop does not loop 5 iterations, because `len(lst) = 5` and `len(lst) - 1 = 4`, your variable `i` will only loop 4 times which is 0,1,2,3

Thus not display the element `9` in your list!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `len(list)` when you're going to iterate every element in the list.

And,

you need to use `len(list) - 1` when you need every element except the last element in the list.